# Struggling to build electron + react app with external images

Tags: reactjs, electron

Im trying to build my first electron + react app using Electron React Boilerplate. Everything works fine except i can't find any info on how to add external images to my react app. I have data.json file and my react app reads it content through IPC. data.json is just a simple list of images that must be loaded onto react page. I have no idea how to approach this

Comment: https://www.debugandrelease.com/how-to-load-images-in-electron-applications/ you google it

Comment: im not sure exactly whats happening in this example. i can add images through import, like icons, backgrounds and so on. but i can't do it dynamically. i need load images that is not packed into app